# MVC how to display boolean table values as alternative text values instead

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a class named `InvoiceLine` which has the following properties.

```
public class InvoiceLine : IEntity
    {
        ...

        public virtual int? OfficeUserId { get; set; }
        public virtual int? FieldUserId { get; set; }
        public virtual bool? OfficeApproved { get; set; }
        public virtual string OfficeRejectionReason { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? OfficeApprovedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual bool? FieldApproved { get; set; }
        public virtual string FieldRejectionReason { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? FieldApprovedDate { get; set; }

        ...

        public virtual User OfficeUser { get; set; }
        public virtual User FieldUser { get; set; }

        ...
}
```

I want to display in a table something like:

```
<td>Office sign off: Conan the Barbarian Approved</td>
<td>Field sign off: Steve the snake Not Approved</td>
```

So I wrote:

```
<td>Office sign off:
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => invoiceLine.OfficeUser.UserName)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => invoiceLine.OfficeApproved)
                    </td>
                    <td>Field sign off:
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => invoiceLine.FieldUser.UserName)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => invoiceLine.FieldApproved)
                    </td>
```

Obviously this doesn't give the required format and delivers something like:

```
<td>
Office sign off: Conan the Barbarian
<select class="tri-state list-box" disabled="disabled">
<option value="">Not Set</option>
<option value="true" selected="selected">True</option>
<option value="false">False</option>
</select>
</td>

<td>
Office sign off: Steve the snake
<select class="tri-state list-box" disabled="disabled">
<option value="">Not Set</option>
<option value="true">True</option>
<option value="false" selected="selected">False</option>
</select>
</td>
```

So I'm getting the boolean values for the approvals in dropdownlists which makes sense. How to I get it to display instead as I described earlier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is just ignore the built in helpers and write it out as follows:

```
@( invoiceLine.FieldApproved.HasValue ? (invoiceLine.FieldApproved.Value ? "Approved" : "Not Approved"):"Not Specified" )
```

However, your best bet is to write your own HTML handler I think (especially if this is a common task and will be used on a details page etc).

```
public static MvcHtmlString ApprovedBoolFor<TModel, bool?>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, bool?>> selector)
{
    var prop = selector.Compile().Invoke(html.ViewData.Model);
    var appVal = prop.HasValue ?
              (prop.Value ? "Approved" : "Not Approved")
              : "Not specified";

    return new MvcHtmlString(appVal);
}
```

Comment: that looks promising but I'm unsure where the selector is coming from.

Comment: I'm still not sure that's quite right because I'm getting squigglies under HasValue and Value. As in the compiler has no idea what they are

Comment: sorry, need to specify the type or cast it. I'll have to test the latest edit, but gotta run. will pop back in a bit.